# YUI3 dragProxy not working properly

Tags: yui3

While draging a node I do not want to change the original position of the node but I want to move another div (proxyNOde).

I am trying the code below but it takes the original node while dragging.

```
YUI().use('console', 'dd-drag','dd-constrain','dd-proxy', function(Y) {
    var drag = new Y.DD.Drag({
        node: '#'+picClone.id,
        dragMode: 'intersect'
     }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDProxy, {
        moveOnEnd: true
    }).plug(Y.Plugin.DDConstrained, {
        constrain2node: '#pictureContainer'
    });

    drag.on('drag:start', function() {
        var p = this.get('dragNode'),
            n = this.get('node');
            if (!this._playerStart) {
                this._playerStart = this.nodeXY;
            }
        p.set('innerHTML',_this.getDragProxyNode().innerHTML);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you'll need to modify your Y.Plugin.DDProxy configuration as depicted below:

```
.plug(Y.Plugin.DDProxy, {
  moveOnEnd: false,
  cloneNode: true
});
```